# ODE Solvers Running Slowly When Ran Together

Tags: matlab, runge-kutta

I have a custom implementation of some ODE solvers for a class.  I'm having a problem where if I make the time step `dt` smaller than `.2`, the program will stall.  However, if I comment out one of the Runge-Kutta solvers, it will execute very quickly, and I can switch which one is commented out so I can get the solution from both solvers.  I'm wondering how to fix this.  I've been trying to find some way that one solver might be interfering with the other, but I don't see how this could be happening.

Implementation:

```
global dt;
dt = .5;  % going below ~.25 makes the program take a very long time to exit

g = 1;
c_d = 2;
m = 3;

tf = 15;

dudt = @(t, u) g - (c_d/m) * u.^2

[t_euler, u_euler] = euler(dudt, [0, tf], 0);
[t_rk4, u_rk4] = rk4(dudt, [0, tf], 0); % either of this one or rk2
                                        % can be commented out to make the program
                                        % run quickly, but rk2 and rk4 cannot be
                                        % run at the same time
[t_rk2, u_rk2] = rk2(dudt, [0, tf], 0);


%% rk4.m %%

function [t, u] = rk4(odefun, tspan, u0)

t0 = tspan(1);
t = [ t0 ];
t_new = t0;
global dt;
tf = tspan(2);
u_new = u0;

u = [ u0 ];

while (t_new < tf)
   if (t_new + dt > tf)
        dt = tf - t_new;
    end

    k1 = dt * odefun(t_new, u_new);
    k2 = dt * odefun(t_new + dt/2, u_new + k1/2);
    k3 = dt * odefun(t_new + dt/2, u_new + k2/2);
    k4 = dt * odefun(t_new + dt, u_new + k3);

    u_new = u_new + 1/6 * (k1 + 2*k2 + 2*k3 + k4);
    % rk2.m is the same as rk4.m, except u_new = u_new + k2
    % euler.m is also the same, except u_new = u_new + k1
    u = [ u, u_new ];

    t_new = t_new + dt;
    t = [ t, t_new ];
end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When computing the interval length for the last step to meet `tf` exactly, you reduce the global variable `dt`, and in the other method the now smaller value of `dt` is used. With your data, you might have the new `dt` as small as `1e-16` or even `0`.

You want to treat the global `dt` as a constant, perhaps use a local variable `h` instead of `dt`. Or pass `dt` as parameter of the functions.

Comment: That was it exactly.  Thank you very much!